# Curl install of nodejs wasn't success and now some error in update Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I was trying to install nodeJs on Ubuntu 23.04 and I used from node js git https://github.com/nodesource/distributions

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | sudo -E bash - &&\
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

So after it wasn't installed and give an error. I got some error in Software update and can't fix it.
[apt update can't update this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qXmo.png)

I was trying to install node.js other way and I did it, but this I can't fix